# Converting Excel multi-sheets into CSV on ADLS using Azure Automation with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-data-lake-gen2

Running PowerShell code in an Azure Automation Account.  Have loaded ExcelImport library and am connecting OK to my ADLS storage account to read my Excel Files.

I'm wanting to read a number of XLSX files from an ADLS Storage Account and parse through each to get the Worksheets then export each worksheet to another folder on the same ADLS Storage account.  I'm getting the code to pick up the Excel files, run through each with the Worksheet names beautifully but I don't get the files saved as a CSV into my csv folder at the end.  I've tried this with and without the Set-AzStorageBlobContent in the Import-Excel command.

The code runs through no problem, no errors, no warnings, but no files saved, what am I missing or doing wrong? :(

```html
########## Get Base Filename from full folder name ############
function Get-UDF-BaseFile 
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $fileLocation
    )
    $baseFile = $fileLocation -split, "/", -1
    #$basePrefix = $baseFile -split, ".",1
    Return $baseFile[-1]
}


#### For Each Excel File, get the worksheets and save each as CSV to ADLS ########
Function Export-UDF-XLToCSV ($excelFileName, $csvLoc)
{
    Write-Output $excelFileName
    $xl = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $excelFileName
    $excelFile = Get-UDF-BaseFile($excelFileName)
    $excelFilePrefix = $excelFile.Split(".")[0]
    $sheets = (Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path $excelFileName).Name
    foreach ($sheet in $sheets)
    {
        $n = $excelFilePrefix + "__" + $sheet
        $outputFile = $csvLoc + $n + ".csv"
        Import-Excel -WorksheetName $sheet -Path $excelFileName 
          | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation 
          | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -File $outputFile -Context $SAContext
         Write-Output "Excel File: $($excelFile), Exporting Sheet: $($sheet) to $($outputFile)"
    }
    Close-ExcelPackage $xl
}

  #######################################################################
  # Start of Main Code
  #######################################################################
  $StorageAccountName = "mystorageaccount"
  $ResourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup-rg"

  $StorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $StorageAccountName 
    | -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
  $SAContext = $StorageAccount.Context

  $ContainerName = "root"
  $BlobDirRoot = "sources/myexports"
  $BlobDir = $BlobDirRoot + "/excel/*.xlsx"
  $listOfFiles = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Blob $BlobDir -Context $SAContext
  $DestinationDir = $BlobDirRoot + "/csv/"

  foreach ($file in $listOfFiles) 
  {
    $fileContent = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Blob $file.Name 
      | -Context $SAContext
    Export-UDF-XLToCSV -excelFileName $file.Name -csvLoc $DestinationDir
  }
```

Comment: Well, for one if you want to line wrap at a pipe the pipe needs to be at the end of the line not the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Not the issue here

Comment: How is that not the issue? Your `Import-Excel -WorksheetName $sheet -Path $excelFileName` call does not store the data in a variable, and does not pipe it to anything, so it should just output to the console at that point. Then ` | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation` pipes nothing to the `Export-Csv` call, so nothing is being exported to the CSV file. Similarly the next line pipes nothing to `Set-AzStorageBlobContent`, so nothing is set there. That one should have the pipe in front of it removed entirely really.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I modified it to be the following and this now works, so taken from the foreach part of the code:

```html
    foreach ($sheet in $sheets)
    {
        $n = $excelFilePrefix + "__" + $sheet
        $outputFile = $csvLoc + $n + ".csv"
    $tempFile = "C:\Temp\$($outputFile)"
        $excelData = Import-Excel -WorksheetName $sheet -Path $excelFileName | 
           ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
    $excelData | Out-File $tempFile
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Blob $outputFile |
          -File $tempFile -Context $SAContext -Force
    Write-Output "Excel File: $($excelFile), Exporting Sheet: $($sheet) to $($outputFile)"
    }
```

Comment: My formatting didn't come out quite as I wanted with the indents, but at least this now works